# Slack Webhook Truncating Data ( text )

Tags: jinja2, slack

I am trying to send a Slack Webhook Notification which works fine.

But it truncates the output which is a concern,

Here below is my jinja which my app uses to send notification.

What i am trying to solve here, is to make sure, entire data which is derived is passed on slack channel

```
{
  "channel": "alerts",
  "attachments": [
      {
          "fallback": "Plain-text summary of the attachment.",
          "color": "#2eb886",
          "title": "Slack API Documentation",
          "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
          "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
          "fields": [
               {
                  "title":"Account",
                  "value":"{{account|default("")}} ({{ account_id|default("N/A") }})",
                  "short": true
               },
               {
                  "title":"Region",
                  "value":"{{ region|default("N/A") }}",
                  "short": true
               },
               {
                  "title":"Resources",
                  {% if resources %}
                  "value":"Volume Id \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t| VolumeType \t | Size \t\t | State \t\t\t | Encrypted \n{% for resource in resources %}{{ resource['VolumeId'] }} \t | {{ resource['VolumeType'] }} \t\t\t\t\t | {{ resource['Size'] }} \t\t| {{ resource['State'] }} \t\t\t | {{ resource['Encrypted'] }}\n{% endfor %}"
                  {% else %}
                  "value": "No resources found!"
                  {% endif %}
               }
          ],
      }
  ]
}
```

Tried the above jinja

Comment: I think the problem is 
value string No Provide a string identifying this specific action. It will be sent to your Action URL along with the name and attachment's callback_id. If providing multiple actions with the same name, value can be strategically used to differentiate intent. Your value may contain up to 2000 characters.